# Is Avast antivirus reading my emails?

Tags: firefox, email, avast

So, I just found out that Avast is adding it's signature to my outgoing emails. I did a bit of googling to learn a bit more about this issue, and found this question: [How does avast! add a signature into my webmail?](https://superuser.com/questions/1066611/how-does-avast-add-a-signature-into-my-webmail)

According to the accepted (and only) answer, Avast is intercepting, decrypting, modifying, and re-encrypting emails in order to add the signature. However, some of the comments below the answer state that the answer is wrong.

So, is Avast reading or capable of reading my emails? And if so, should I be concerned?

I'm using firefox and Gmail. The avast online security addon is installed but disabled.

Comment: Ok, but that isn't what I asked. The signature aside, can avast read my emails? Also, the addon is disabled, and the signature "feature" being truly optional is debatable, seeing as Avast never notified me or asked permission to modify my emails, and is set to do this by default without my knowledge.

Comment: whether or not they "have better things to do" is not my concern. If a software that claims to be antivirus is behaving like malware and hacking into private correspondences, that is a serious problem, both in terms of privacy and security.

Comment: And no, installing a software does not give permission for that software to start hacking into and stealing private data. That's like stating that installing windows gives microsoft the right to set up a keylogger and record everything I type, which, again, would be a serious problem in terms of both privacy and security.

Comment: So uninstall the software if you are worried.  I cannot say nor anyone here can say or make the claim that Avast does or doesn't harvest emails.  I can say that if you are that worried use different software. I can also say that Avast has better things to do then harvest emails.  We can't possibly know the answer to that question.When you installed Avast you installed it with his feature enabled, this in that way, you gave permission for the product to scan your emails for malicious attachments

Comment: Again, whether or not Avast as a company has better things to do is not my concern. There's this thing called identity theft. Based on your responses can I assume you've never heard of it?

Comment: I despise Avast as a company.  I hate AVG even more for corrupting my emails over a decade due to broken software.

Comment: well, I'm gonna shoot avast an email and see what they have to say about this.

Comment: They will send you a nice foil hat, I'm sure.

Comment: And I'm so sure that your naive trust will prove a great benefit to you.